# Add Image on top a container and create columns

Tags: html, css, header, containers

The problem is that i don't know how is this type of code called, so it's kinda hard for me to search it here.

What i need to do is to add a top Background on a Container so its like this:

"Text Header" - below that i want to have a *background to separate content from the header* and then *create a 3 layer columns* (1 up divided in 2 and a complete one below that)

`jsfiddle.net/U56UA/` (Sorry idk how to code it)

The *objective* of the entire container is to have 1 layer for basic information, a second layer to show what membership it has and the one below for personal information(services, etc.)

**It would be awesome if someone could explain me (Im learning, sorry) or send some website where it's explained.**

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/4BVfeFxj (Current Index)
http://pastebin.com/56Mtk1yg (Current CSS)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand either your fiddle nor your image. Could you perhaps share an image of the intended merged end result?

Comment: The image and the description don't match. Layers? You need basic CSS and html skills to achieve the layout in the image. http://teamtreehouse.com/

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. I hope this image illustrates what i tryied to explain with my lack of knowledge.
http://i.imgur.com/EBsBHgx.png

Comment: Add your attempted code to your question otherwise it will be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/J5ZmC/)**</kbd> based upon your image.

```
<div class="container">

  <header>Stats</header>

  <section class="left">
    <span>LEFT</span>
  </section>

  <section class="right">
    <span>RIGHT</span>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <span>CONTENT</span>
  </footer>

</div>
```

---

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;

  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
header {
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 97.8%;
  min-height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 47.8%;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}
```

Comment: This one also did hit the right key, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [this modification](http://jsfiddle.net/crew1251/U56UA/1/%29) of your JSFiddle:

**CSS:**

```
.container {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 77%);
}
.container table {
    width:100%;

}
.container table tr td,th{
    padding: 5px;

}
.container table td {
    border:1px solid gray;

}
.container .statshead {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="15">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="statshead">
            Statictic
        </th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Text Demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Text Demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="statshead">
            Information
        </th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Text Demo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Text Demo</td>
    </tr>

</table></div>
```